# What's the most reliable method for cross-platform alarm signal handling or execution timeouts in Perl?

Tags: postgresql, perl, timeout, signals, alarm

I've added advisory locking to [Sqitch](https://sqitch.org), using [Postgres advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) and [MySQL GET_LOCK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locking-functions.html). This feature prevents more than one instance of Sqitch from deploying to a database at one time. This works great, but I wanted to add a lock timeout, too, so that one never finds a CI/CD process hung for hours or days because something went amiss.

MySQL's `GET_LOCK()` supports a timeout argument, but Postgres advisory locks do not. Since I thought it likely that other database engines would also not have timeouts, I thought it best to implement the timeout in Perl. Following the DBI manual, I used [Sys::SigAction](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sys::SigAction) to set and handle [the timeout](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/blob/e75292994b69448ca9b039ab93881584823595e1/lib/App/Sqitch/Engine.pm#L1043-L1047):

```perl
# Try waiting for the lock.
require App::Sqitch::SigAction;
return $self->_locked(1) unless App::Sqitch::SigAction::timeout_call($wait, sub {
    $self->wait_lock
});
```

I also added [tests](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/blob/e75292994b69448ca9b039ab93881584823595e1/t/lib/DBIEngineTest.pm#L1748-L1762) to confirm it works with both MySQL and Postgres. So far so good.

Alas, Sys::SigAction [does not work on Windows](https://github.com/labaxter/sys-sigaction/blob/3c6112c7a26efbdffd0745d89fd70a0eeebca0da/Makefile.PL#L11-L25). I took a stab and [testing it on Windows](https://github.com/theory/sys-sigaction/runs/3900853084), but since Windows Perl is not compiled with `d_sigaction`, which [Sys::SigAction also requires](https://github.com/labaxter/sys-sigaction/blob/3c6112c7a26efbdffd0745d89fd70a0eeebca0da/Makefile.PL#L48-L57), I didn't get far. I tried implementing the [Perl-standard `alarm`/`$SIG{ALRM}` pattern](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm), but it failed to send the signal while waiting on the Postgres lock.

Which has led me here and to my question: What is the best cross-platform pattern for timing out some execution in Perl? Ideally it has a straight-forward interface, works on *nix and Windows, and effectively handles breaking out of a database query.

Comment: Widnows doesn't have signals. (It does have something similar for Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Break, but that's it.) So the question as asked has no answer. There's no general cross-platform general timeout mechanism. There are solutions for specific domains. For example, if you want to do IO, you could use one of the async IO libraries. If you want to kill the whole process, you can use a signal in unix and a sleeping thread in Windows. etc The MySQL library is probably written in terms of unix syscalls (`open`, `write`, etc and expect to you to use signals) rather than with Windows in mind.

Comment: (This is not a "unix is better than Windows thing, this is about C libraries (and Perl code too) being almost always written as unix programs rather than Windows programs, even those meant to run on Windows. The OSes have fundamentally different approaches to doing things, and the C std library is very unix centric.)

Comment: What would an async io library look like? The only thing it needs to time out is a call [like](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/blob/e75292994b69448ca9b039ab93881584823595e1/lib/App/Sqitch/Engine/pg.pm#L275) `$dbh->do('SELECT pg_advisory_lock(75474063)');`. Since it acquires a database session lock, though, it can't be a separate process or thread.

Comment: Not useful here since you're not doing IO. Though there could be async DB libraries?

Comment: In postgres there is `pg_try_advisory_lock ( key )` which returns false instead of blocking.

Comment: Yeah I'm calling `pg_try_advisory_lock()` first, and falling back on `pg_advisory_lock()` if it returns false. Might have to switch to polling if there is no other practical way to do a timeout (maybe some sort of async framework?).

Comment: Looks like the simplest thing to do is poll with a backoff; [Algorithm::Backoff::Exponential](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Backoff::Exponential) looks straightforward. Now to decide whether to use Sys::SigAction where supported, or just always poll instead.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up ditching Sys::SigAction following discussion here and elsewhere, and instead switched to:

1. Letting the database handle the timeout, as MySQL's `get_lock()` does
2. Adding a simple interface for [polling with exponential backoff](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/blob/f00b71918ac65408edb45457e178327640685e55/lib/App/Sqitch/Engine.pm#L1054-L1072) and timeout that engines can use to poll for a lock instead of waiting (similar to [Retry::Backoff](https://metacpan.org/pod/Retry::Backoff))
3. Switching the Postgres implementation to use the async query support in DBD::Pg to send off the lock request, and uses the backoff/timeout interface to check to see if it has returned and cancel the query if it times out

I was especially pleased to realize I could do #3, as I originally used the timeout/backoff interface to poll with `pg_try_advisory_lock( key )`, which just feels heavy. Better to asynchronously call `pg_advisory_lock ( key )` and poll for its response. It looks like [this](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/blob/f00b71918ac65408edb45457e178327640685e55/lib/App/Sqitch/Engine/pg.pm#L275-L290):

```perl
sub wait_lock {
    my $self = shift;
    # Asyncronouslly request a lock with an indefinite wait.
    my $dbh = $self->dbh;
    $dbh->do(
        'SELECT pg_advisory_lock(75474063)',
        { pg_async => DBD::Pg::PG_ASYNC() },
    );

    # Use _timeout to periodically check for the result.
    return 1 if $self->_timeout(sub { $dbh->pg_ready && $dbh->pg_result });

    # Timed out, cancel the query and return false.
    $dbh->pg_cancel;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course the [MySQL implementation](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/blob/f00b71918ac65408edb45457e178327640685e55/lib/App/Sqitch/Engine/mysql.pm#L316-L322) is simpler, since `get_lock()` does all the work:

```perl
sub wait_lock {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->dbh->selectcol_arrayref(
        q{SELECT get_lock('sqitch working', ?)},
        undef, $self->lock_timeout
    )->[0]
}
```